# Show that if $f \in L^p$, then so is $T_x(f)$ for any $x ∈ \Bbb R$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let, $1 ≤ p ≤ ∞$. Show that, for any $x∈ \Bbb R$ and any $f∈L^p(\lambda)$ ,one has $T_x(f) (:= f(x+·) ∈ L^p$ and $||T_x(f)||_p = ||f||_p$

I started with indicator functions.

Let, $f=1_B$ for some Borel set, then  $\int|T_x(f)|^p d\lambda = \int(1_{B+x})^p d\lambda= \int 1_{B+x} d\lambda = \lambda(B+x)=\lambda(B)=\int|f|^p d\lambda $

Similarly, for simple functions.

Taking increasing limits, same is true for non-negative measurable functions.

Let, $f$ be measurable and thus, $f=f^+ - f^-$. Similarly, $T_x(f)={T_x(f)}^+ -{T_x(f)}^-$

$\int|T_x(f)|^p d\lambda = \int|T_x(f)^+ - T_x(f)^- |^p d\lambda =$

The terminal terms fit in nicely for the equality with terms of same form for $f$ , but how to deal with the mixed terms, like there will be terms of the form, $\int |T_x(f)^+|^l |T_x(f)^-|^{p-l} d\lambda$ , then how to manipulate these terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should observe that at least one of $T_x(f)^+$ and $T_x(f)^-$ equals zero. Thus
$$|T_x(f)|^p = |T_x(f)^+ - T_x(f)^-|^p = |T_x(f)^+|^p + |T_x(f)^-|^p.$$

Comment: Can you kindly explain the observation in a bit more detail?

Comment: Is it clear that one of $T_x(f)^+$ and $T_x(f)^-$ equals zero?

Comment: No. It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: Note $g^+ = g$ if $g > 0$ and equals $0$ otherwise, $g^- = -g$ if $g < 0$ and equals zero otherwise. You can't simultaneously have $g > 0$ and $g < 0$, so at least one of $g^+$, $g^-$ is zero.

Comment: I am considering $T_x (f)$ for  a general measurable function, so shouldn't it have both a positive and a negative part?

Comment: Yes, and at any point at least one of them equals zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85502/discussion-between-coherent-and-umberto-p).